# Jfreechart: Drawing line arrow in gantt chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, graphics2d, gantt-chart

I want to draw some vertical lines to track the tasks as shown by the red lines in the figure below. I believe the lines can be drawn using the Gantt Renderer.

What I want to is store the coordinates of the end points of the lines during drawing of the tasks and then finally draw those lines in the plot.

[image: Task Line Tracker]

I want to know if there is a method that lets you draw anything on the plot and whether this is the right way to approach this problem.

Here is my code for the gantt renderer:

```
public class Renderer extends GanttRenderer {


    private Color markerColorChannel = Color.BLUE;
    private Color markerColorFunction = new Color(138,43,226);
    private Color functionDurationMarkerColor = new Color(0,100,0);
    private boolean functionTrace = false;
    private List<ProcessorTask> listOfDrawingTask = new ArrayList<ProcessorTask>();

    /**
     * CONSTRUCTOR
     * 
     * @param model
     */
    public Renderer() {


    }

    /**
     * This method is used to draw the task/subtasks for each channel or row item. 
     * The method is called each time the gannt chart is repainted: including zooming, 
     * sliding and changes to gannt chart input configurations.
     *
     * @param g2 The graphics device.
     * @param state The renderer state.
     * @param dataArea The data plot area.
     * @param plot The plot.
     * @param domainAxis The domain axis.
     * @param rangeAxis The range axis.
     * @param dataset The set of data to be drawn 
     * @param row The row index (zero-based).
     * @param column Indicates the index of the task item to be drawn (starts from zero)
     */
    // DRAW TASKS
    @Override
    protected void drawTasks(Graphics2D g2, CategoryItemRendererState state, Rectangle2D dataArea, CategoryPlot plot, CategoryAxis domainAxis,
            ValueAxis rangeAxis, GanttCategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column) {

        try {

//          plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
//          plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

//           System.out.println("ROW: " + row + " COL: " + column + " time " + System.currentTimeMillis());

             /* Get the total number of subtasks in the channel or row item*/
            int count = dataset.getSubIntervalCount(row, column);

            /* If the item contains no subtask the count is zero. Then draw only the single task. */
            if (count == 0) {
                drawTask(g2, state, dataArea, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, row, column);
            }

            /*If the item contains subtasks, loop through each of them*/
            for (int subinterval = 0; subinterval < count; subinterval++) {

                RectangleEdge rangeAxisLocation = plot.getRangeAxisEdge();
                Number subtaskStart;    // start time
                Number subtaskEnd;      // end time
                double subtaskStartTranslated;
                double subtaskEndTranslated;

                /* Sub task start time */
                subtaskStart = dataset.getStartValue(row, column, subinterval);
                if (subtaskStart == null) {
                    System.out.println("No starting time for subtask " + subinterval + " item " + column + " found!");
                    return;
                }
                subtaskStartTranslated = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(subtaskStart.doubleValue(), dataArea, rangeAxisLocation);

                /* Sub task end time */
                subtaskEnd = dataset.getEndValue(row, column, subinterval);
                if (subtaskEnd == null) {
                    System.out.println("No end time for subtask " + subinterval + " item " + column + " found!");
                    return;
                }
                subtaskEndTranslated = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(subtaskEnd.doubleValue(), dataArea, rangeAxisLocation);


                /*Set the rectangular bar properties*/
                double rectYAxisStart;  
                double rectLength;
                double rectBreadth;
                Rectangle2D bar = null;
                Number percent; // task percentage completion

                rectYAxisStart = calculateBarW0(plot, plot.getOrientation(), dataArea, domainAxis, state, row, column); 
                rectLength = Math.abs(subtaskEndTranslated - subtaskStartTranslated);
                rectBreadth = state.getBarWidth();
                percent = dataset.getPercentComplete(row, column, subinterval);

                /*Draw the rectangular bar*/
                if (plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {      // horizontal is applied for the ganntchart
                    bar = new Rectangle2D.Double(subtaskStartTranslated, rectYAxisStart, rectLength, rectBreadth);
                } else if (plot.getOrientation() == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
                    bar = new Rectangle2D.Double(rectYAxisStart, subtaskStartTranslated, rectBreadth, rectLength);
                }


                /*Drawing the task completion bar in the subtask bar: 
                 * This feature is currently not needed in the gantt chart*/

                /* Painting the task/subtask */
                Paint seriesPaint = getItemPaint(row, column, subinterval);
                g2.setPaint(seriesPaint);
                g2.fill(bar);

                if (isDrawBarOutline() && state.getBarWidth() > BAR_OUTLINE_WIDTH_THRESHOLD) {
                    g2.setStroke(getItemStroke(row, column));
                    g2.setPaint(getItemOutlinePaint(row, column));
                    g2.draw(bar);

                }


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to paint the subtasks of a channel or row item
     * @param row
     * @param col Index of the channel or the row item
     * @param subinterval   Index of the subtask
     * @return  Paint Item
     */
    private Paint getItemPaint(int row, int col, int subinterval) {
        return this.listOfDrawingTask.get(col).getSubTaskColorList().get(subinterval);
    }
}
```

Update:

It seems that the LineAnnotations is the best way to implement the lines.
[Link1](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23888)

Comment: Agree on using `CategoryLineAnnotation`; BTW, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines can be added onto the Gantt Chart using the CategoryLineAnnotation. The line annotations are added to the plot.

```
 CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
 plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("Category 2", 5.0, 
          "Category 4", 8.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(2.0f)));
```

Here is an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [example](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23888) by [David Gilbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592874/david-gilbert):

```
        /* ===========================================================
        * JFreeChart : a free chart library for the Java(tm) platform
        * ===========================================================
        *
        * (C) Copyright 2000-2007, by Object Refinery Limited and Contributors.
        *
        * Project Info:  http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html
        *
        * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it 
        * under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by 
        * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or 
        * (at your option) any later version.
        *
        * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but 
        * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY 
        * or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public 
        * License for more details.
        *
        * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
        * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
        * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, 
        * USA.  
        *
        * [Java is a trademark or registered trademark of Sun Microsystems, Inc. 
        * in the United States and other countries.]
        *
        * ------------------
        * BarChartDemo1.java
        * ------------------
        * (C) Copyright 2003-2007, by Object Refinery Limited and Contributors.
        *
        * Original Author:  David Gilbert (for Object Refinery Limited);
        * Contributor(s):   ;
        *
        * Changes
        * -------
        * 09-Mar-2005 : Version 1 (DG);
        *
        */

        package org.jfree.chart.demo;

        import java.awt.BasicStroke;
        import java.awt.Color;
        import java.awt.Dimension;
        import java.awt.GradientPaint;

        import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
        import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
        import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
        import org.jfree.chart.annotations.CategoryLineAnnotation;
        import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
        import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryLabelPositions;
        import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
        import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
        import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
        import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
        import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
        import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
        import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
        import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

        /**
        * A simple demonstration application showing how to create a bar chart.
        */
        public class BarChartDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {

            /**
             * Creates a new demo instance.
             *
             * @param title  the frame title.
             */
            public BarChartDemo1(String title) {
                super(title);
                CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
                JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
                ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
                chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
                setContentPane(chartPanel);
            }

            /**
             * Returns a sample dataset.
             * 
             * @return The dataset.
             */
            private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {

                // row keys...
                String series1 = "First";
                String series2 = "Second";
                String series3 = "Third";

                // column keys...
                String category1 = "Category 1";
                String category2 = "Category 2";
                String category3 = "Category 3";
                String category4 = "Category 4";
                String category5 = "Category 5";

                // create the dataset...
                DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

                dataset.addValue(1.0, series1, category1);
                dataset.addValue(4.0, series1, category2);
                dataset.addValue(3.0, series1, category3);
                dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category4);
                dataset.addValue(5.0, series1, category5);

                dataset.addValue(5.0, series2, category1);
                dataset.addValue(7.0, series2, category2);
                dataset.addValue(6.0, series2, category3);
                dataset.addValue(8.0, series2, category4);
                dataset.addValue(4.0, series2, category5);

                dataset.addValue(4.0, series3, category1);
                dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category2);
                dataset.addValue(2.0, series3, category3);
                dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category4);
                dataset.addValue(6.0, series3, category5);

                return dataset;

            }

            /**
             * Creates a sample chart.
             * 
             * @param dataset  the dataset.
             * 
             * @return The chart.
             */
            private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {

                // create the chart...
                JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                    "Bar Chart Demo 1",       // chart title
                    "Category",               // domain axis label
                    "Value",                  // range axis label
                    dataset,                  // data
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                    true,                     // include legend
                    true,                     // tooltips?
                    false                     // URLs?
                );

                // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...

                // set the background color for the chart...
                chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

                // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
                CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
                plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
                plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
                plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);
                plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

                plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("Category 2", 5.0, 
                      "Category 4", 8.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(2.0f)));

                // ******************************************************************
                //  More than 150 demo applications are included with the JFreeChart
                //  Developer Guide...for more information, see:
                //
                //  >   http://www.object-refinery.com/jfreechart/guide.html
                //
                // ******************************************************************

                // set the range axis to display integers only...
                final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
                rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

                // disable bar outlines...
                BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
                renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);

                // set up gradient paints for series...
                GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.blue, 
                        0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0, 0, 64));
                GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.green, 
                        0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(0, 64, 0));
                GradientPaint gp2 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, Color.red, 
                        0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(64, 0, 0));
                renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
                renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, gp1);
                renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, gp2);

                CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
                domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
                        CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(
                                Math.PI / 6.0));
                // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.

                return chart;

            }

            /**
             * Starting point for the demonstration application.
             *
             * @param args  ignored.
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                BarChartDemo1 demo = new BarChartDemo1("Bar Chart Demo 1");
                demo.pack();
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
                demo.setVisible(true);
            }

        }
```